# Razor - Apply random CSS class from array

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have searched everywhere for an answer to this, to no avail.  If already answered somewhere else, then my apologies.

Here is my current code:

```
    @{
      foreach (var item in Model.Activities)
      {
          <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 over-f-hidden">
              <div class="block-main">
                  <div class="block-inner green">
                      <br />
                      <h5>@item.ActivityName</h5>
                      <h4><span><a href="@Url.Action("ScanRequest","Home",new { id = item.id })" style="text-decoration: none">SELECT THIS ACTIVITY</a></span></h4>
                      <br />
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      }
  }
```

In addition, I have three CSS classes called:

```
.red
.green
.yellow
```

In my code, for the class="block-inner green", I would like the replace "green" with a randomly chosen class from my list of three classes.  Repeating is fine.

Elsewhere in the body of my View, I added this:

```
    @{ 
        string[] color = { "red", "yellow", "green" };
    }
```

But I don't know how to call a random member of that array as a class for the div using Razor.

Is there a way to accomplish this strictly from within the View?

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 @{ 
   string[] color = { "red", "yellow", "green" };
   Random  RD=new Random();
  }
 @foreach (var item in Model.Activities)
  { 
   <div class="block-inner @(color[RD.next(0,2)])">...</div>
  }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you for your quick and clear answer.

Comment: Just a note: the class should read @(color[RD.Next(0,3)]) to work properly.  Doesn't mean that your answer didn't give me exactly what I needed to resolve my issue.  Thanks again.